# AWS Elastic Beanstalk single container, how do I deploy a new container to an existing enviroment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an elastic beanstalk application with an existing environment. When originally making the environment, the config pulled the container from ECR using the URL I provided in the docker-compose.yml file. However, after building a new container, I am not sure how to force the existing environment (ex: staging) to pull the new image. When running 'eb create' it complains unless I create a new environment. Is there a command to pull a new container to an existing environment?

Comment: Usually you would use `eb deoloy` for that. Have you tried that?

Comment: @Marcin It is my understanding that eb deploy doesn't rebuild the container, just deploys the new code.